# Spark Driver running from Tomcat9, Unable to load files into spark session inside java parallel Stream

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, tomcat9

We have a requirement to load multiple parquet files into Spark session and count the number of records in each parquet file. We thought to do it by parallelly. So we chose java 1.8 parallel stream concept but it is throwing parquet file exception. If we use the sequential stream concept then no issues. But we want to load all files parallelly.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hdfs://NNcluster/finalsnappy/2019/4/8291/table_8291_69_2019_04_01", "hdfs://NNcluster/finalsnappy/2019/4/8291/table_8291_69_2019_04_02");
list.parallelStream().forEach(fileName-> {
    SparkSession spark = get_spark_session();// gets spark session
    Dataset<Row> tmpDS = spark.read().format("parquet").load(fileName);
    tmpDS.show();
    System.out.println(tmpDS.count());
});
```

Following exception, we are getting if parallelStream() method used,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$12
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.InnerClosureFinder$$anon$4.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:429)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClosureClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:794)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:793)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:793)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:555)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
        at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp.lambda$0(test_jsp.java:210)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

But all the Jars are properly loaded. If we remove parallelStream() method on list then no issues working properly as like below,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hdfs://NNcluster/finalsnappy/2019/4/8291/table_8291_69_2019_04_01", "hdfs://NNcluster/finalsnappy/2019/4/8291/table_8291_69_2019_04_02");
list.forEach(fileName-> {
    SparkSession spark = get_spark_session();// gets spark session
    Dataset<Row> tmpDS = spark.read().format("parquet").load(fileName);
    tmpDS.show();
    System.out.println(tmpDS.count());
});
```

Please, someone help us how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Would be nice to know Spark and Hadoop versions.

Comment: @mazaneicha Spark version is 2.3 and Hadoop version is 2.7 we are using

Comment: @mazaneicha : Issue observed only when we add that piece of code in JSP file running in Tomcat9 server. If we run normally as a standalone application then no issue.

Comment: What happens if you try to replace anon function with an explicitly defined `java.util.function.Consumer`? I'm not versed in JSP classloading too well, sorry ...